# Edittext not accepting a capital first letter

Tags: android, capitalize

I have a simple app with `Edittexts` which now (since being forced by android studio to upgrade my emulator to API 27) will simply not accept a capital letter as the first letter. It is still working on my phone (API 21). I have tried the usual TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES and android:inputType="textCapSentences" etc.
This doesn't seem to be the issue tho. It will not accept a capital at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must make use of emulator keyboard to enter the value to edit text. If the focus is on EditText with input type enabled

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

then you will see the keyboard will be CAPS letters for first letter and when you start typing the second letter keyboard will change to small letters.

API < 27 entering from laptop also works. But on 27 it is not working.

Hope this will help you.